# How to emit a signal in QThread loop properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

PyQT QThread seems to be not emitting the signal when it should. I wanted to build a part of my code with PyQt5, that would communicate with a server. I wanted it to be in separate thread because i am operating mostly on images, so it can take some time to send it. I would like to be able to send it and when it receives response from the server it should emit a signal allowing for the next bunch of data to be sent.

Here is the code reduced to minimum.

import sys
    import time

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QThread, QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal


def ask_server():
    return b'some_message_received'

def send_to_server(data):
    pass

class QTClient(QThread):
    result_signal = pyqtSignal(bytes)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self._data = None
        self._result = ' '

    def set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def set_result(self, result):
        self._result = result

    def receive_data(self):
        result = ask_server()
        print('receiving_data{}'.format(result))
        self.result_signal.emit(result)
        self._result = result

    def send_data(self, data):
        send_to_server(data)
        self._data = None

    def run(self):
        broadcast = True
        while broadcast:
            if self._data is not None:
                self.send_data(self._data)
                self.receive_data()
            if self._result is None:
                self.receive_data()


class QtClientManager(QWidget):
    data = pyqtSignal(bytes)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.slam_client = QTClient()
        self.data[bytes].connect(self.slam_client.set_data)
        self._result = ''
        self.slam_client.result_signal[bytes].connect(self.get_result)
        self.thread_slam = QThread()
        self.slam_client.moveToThread(self.thread_slam)
        self.slam_client.start()

    def add_image(self, data):
        print('adding data {}'.format(data))
        self.data.emit(data)

    def get_result(self, result):
        print('getting result data {}'.format(result))
        self._result = result

def loop1():
    for i in range(2):
        qqq.add_image(b'sssss')
        while qqq._result != b'some_message_received':
            time.sleep(1)


def loop2():
    for i in range(2):
        qqq.add_image(b'sssss')
        #while qqq._result != b'some_message_received':
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    qqq = QtClientManager()
    loop1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output for the code with loop1():

```
adding data b'sssss'
receiving_datab'some_message_received'
```

(and it's stuck)

The output for the code with loop2():

```
adding data b'sssss'
receiving_datab'some_message_received'
adding data b'sssss'
receiving_datab'some_message_received'
getting result data b'some_message_received'
getting result data b'some_message_received'
```

It seems to me that the signal emited from within the `receive_data()` is somehow stuck, and not sending data to QtClientManager class. How to do this so it wouldn't blocked?

Comment: The `while` loop in `loop1` is blocking the `Qt` event loop preventing the queued signal from being delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my code, and then found that it was due to the connect function registering multiple times, which in turn led to multiple calls to the emit function